# Can't connect to remote mysql server from rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

When I run:

```
bundle exec rails c
```

I get

```
Mysql2::Error: Access denied for user 'root'@'$HOST' (using password: YES)
```

despite the fact that this works just fine:

```
mysql -h $HOST -P $PORT -u root -p
```

This is my config/database.yml

```
development:
  &defaults
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8mb4
  collation: utf8mb4_unicode_ci
  pool: 5
  host: $HOST
  port: $PORT
  database: $DATABASE
  username: root
  password: $PASSWORD
  reconnect: true
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use bash variables within `config/database.yml` like that. Rails will treat `$HOST` as the string `"$HOST"`, which is what you see happening here

> Mysql2::Error: Access denied for user 'root'@'$HOST' (using password: YES)

Instead, you can use `ENV`

```
development:
  &defaults
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8mb4
  collation: utf8mb4_unicode_ci
  pool: 5
  host: ENV['HOST']
  port: ENV['PORT']
  database: ENV['DATABASE']
  username: root
  password: ENV['PASSWORD']
  reconnect: true
```

Related: http://railsapps.github.io/rails-environment-variables.html

Answer (score 0):

Is the Rails app on localhost?

I think your command line thing translates to

```
mysql -h $HOST -P $PORT -u root@your-computer -p
```

MySQL permissions are based on the host you connect from, so if you are running Rails on a remote host, but doing the command line test on localhost, you are making a different request each time. For example, `root@localhost` should have `DROP` privileges, but `root@$REMOTE_HOST` should not. I would expect that your permissions allow only `root@your-computer` to connect, but not `root@$HOST`.

If this is the case, alter the privileges to add access to root@$HOST using `GRANT`